# Angularjs autocomplete in already created directives

Tags: angularjs

I already have a directive for inputbox. i need to implement Autocomplete feature on that

here is my directive code

```
app.directive("bhAddCategory", ["$rootScope", "$timeout",function($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        scope: {
                rmText: '=bhRmText'

        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>' +
            '<div class="pull-left forDrop"><input type="text" focus-on="focusMe" ng-class="myColonyList" class="effect1" placeholder="Add a colony" data-ng-model="newCategoryName" data-ng-trim="true" ng-keypress="pressEnter($event)"></div>' +
            '<div class="pull-right"><a href=""><img src="/images/greyplus.png" ng-class="{imageoverflow: imageOverflow}" ng-show="loadplus" data-ng-click="addCategory()" alt="add category"><img src="/images/loader.gif" ng-class="{imageoverflow: imageOverflow}" alt="" ng-show="loadgif" class="colonyloder"></a></div >' +
            '</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.loadplus = true;

            scope.pressEnter = function(keyEvent) {
                if (keyEvent.which === 13)
                    scope.addCategory();
            };

            scope.resetNewCategoryName = function() {
                if (scope.rmText) {
                    scope.newCategoryName = '';
                }
            };


        }
    };
}]);
```

How can i implement Auto complete here.

Any Suggestions

Thanks

Comment: You can watch your model and check its value with the data you want to autocomplete from. How should it look like?

Comment: Could you please explain to me more. i m new in angular